# total work done

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a unit force vector parallel to $(-1,0,1)$ in 3 space. what is the work done by $\mathcal{F}$ on a particle moving along the path given via $(t,t^2,t^3)$. So I know work is just $\mathcal{F} \cdot d$ where $\mathcal{F}=(-1,0,1)$ and $d = (1,2t,3t^2)$. The answer key says they integrated this from $0$ to $1$ and they get zero. I don't get zero, could any one explain this better to me? I am studying for the Math GRE subject and this problem showed up as a practice problem. Is my set up correct?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,0,1) \cdot (1,2t,3t^2) dt$$

Comment: I get zero. triple check your math.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is indeed zero. also, you don't even need the integral because the force is constant. so you can simply do $W=\mathbf{\vec F}\cdot \Delta \bf \vec r$ where $\Delta \bf \vec r$ is your displacement.